# NLTK Dutch alpino to english

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to find the quadgram English words I tried to change alpino which downloads the dutch words to en or English but its not working any idea ?

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import alpino
print(alpino.words())
quadgrams=ngrams(alpino.words(),4)
for i in quadgrams:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I tried running your code. But it initially threw error since alpino was not downloaded. Can you try the following snippet before running your code:
`import nltk; nltk.download('alpino')`

Comment: its already downloaded thank you for the comment I searched for it a lot but figured out that they just support Dutch language they don't have ready library's for other languages, already answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching, I figured out that nltk.cropus just has the alpino library for Dutch language and they did not do anything similar like quadgram words in other languages for some reasons.